# Logging in case of multiple tasks in windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task

I want to Log all the logs in different tasks to different logfiles as mentioned in the code snippet below. But with the below code, it does write logs to all the logfiles created in different tasks but Logs written for a task gets merged to logs written by different task.

```
       private static string logFile;
       private static void CreateEmptyFile(string filename)
       {
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Create(filename).Dispose();
            }
       }

       private static void Log(string logMessage, string path)
       {
            string timeStamp = String.Format("{0} {1} - ", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            File.AppendAllText(path, timeStamp + logMessage + Environment.NewLine);
       }

       private static void TaskMethod1(arg1)
       {
            // It calls a bunch of functions and they all log to logfile and all these operation including bunch of functions called(they also log using Log method)
            logFile = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".txt";
            CreateEmptyFile(logFile);
            Log("TaskMethod1", logFile);
       }
       private static async Task TaskMethod()
       {
           while(runningService)
           {
              // Thi will create more than one task in parallel to run and each task can take upto 30 minutes to finish. Based on some condition the upper limit for parallel tasks can go upto 10.
              Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1);
           }
       }
       internal static void Start()
        {
            runningService = true;
            Task1 = Task.Run(() => TaskMethod());
        }
```

I want all the logFiles for different tasks to be separated and content from one task not to be merged with the content of another task.
I suspect this is because of the global variable `logFile` which changes its value as a new task is created but I am not sure, is that the reason for logs written to other task's logs?
How can I resolve this if that is the issue? Should I need to pass `logFile` as an argument to each function instead of declaring it globally.

Comment: Your logFile variable is static, so all the logs will be written to the path which is assigned  LAST.

Comment: Yes, you can't use a static variable in this case. Also, note that using DateTime.Now as the log file name could potentially cause two tasks to attempt to use the same log file name.

Comment: And also File.AppendAllText() is not a good practice for logging (in fact, for almost anything)

Comment: As for the solution, create each Task's log file name distinctly before starting the task and pass it into the task (as a method parameter for example) so that task uses that log File.

Comment: @OguzOzgul so if I remove the static keyword and as I am using DateTime.Now, it should be writing logs to each individual task right? if I start a new task will the global variable also be created again? I mean will the new task use new memory space all together ?

Comment: Please check my answer. You don't have any DateTime field at all. Tasks don't use new memory space, they run as threads from the thread pool which has their own stacks (usually 1 MB) and can share the same global memory space. That is why they have the same log file names when you are using a static variable. So just create and pass logFile information to your tasks and use that

Comment: There was a mistake in my answrr and I correctrd it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the log file name before starting a task and can pass this as a parameter to the worker function:

```
private static async Task TaskMethod()
{
    while (runningService)
    {
        // I am assuming this is not your original code which would create
        // a huge amount of parallel tasks without any checks..
        // if there is no sleep or no wait for synchronization, 
        // many tasks will be created in the same millisecond and will have
        // the same log file name, which would be the least of your problems!
        string logFile = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".txt";
        Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1, logFile));
    }
}
```

And now your TaskMethod1 should look like:

```
// Does not compile. I only add the new string type parameter to the end.
// Your code is not complete, so the answer has to assume that you 
// understand that only one string logFile parameter is appended to the
// end of your parameter list
private static void TaskMethod1(arg1, string logFile)
{
    CreateEmptyFile(logFile);
    Log("TaskMethod1", logFile);
}
```